# MySQL & PHP: Selecting buyer records by product purchased

Tags: php, mysql

I have a somewhat complex MySQL query I'm attempting to derive but I'm just confusing the hell out of myself.

I have several tables: `products, stores, buyer, payment and buyer_purchase.`

buyer_purchase is basically made up of foreign keys. This table more or less links all the other together. The tables are filled up with junk data. The actual records themselves are not as important as the methods used to retrieve them.

[image]

I need to be able to select buyers who have purchased a specific product, how many of that item they've purchased, what store they bought it from, and the payment method used.

It will all be displayed in a webpage using PHP in the following manner:

```
Product1  
name of buyer1  
Payment method  
Number Purchased  
Store purchased From


product2  
Name of buyer1  
Payment  
Number Purchased  
Store Purchased from  
Name of buyer2  
Payment

etc.
```

I have a query that somewhat works:

```
SELECT products.item, stores.seller_name, buyer.f_name, buyer.l_name, payment.company
FROM buyer_purchases
    INNER JOIN products
        ON products.id = buyer_purchases.product_listings_id
    INNER JOIN payment
        ON payment.id = buyer_purchases.buyer_id
    INNER JOIN buyer
        ON buyer.id = buyer_purchases.buyer_id
    INNER JOIN stores
        ON stores.id = buyer_purchases.product_listings_stores_id
    ORDER BY products.item
```

This will return all the data I need in a joined table, but getting it formatted to display as I need is what is confusing me. Obviously, I need to invoke a COUNT to display how many of a given product someone bought, but I'm not sure how to implement it. Further, I think I need GROUP BY rather than ORDER BY, but GROUP BY eliminates all but one record for each product. I've not been able to implement a subquery that MySQL doesn't complain about.

Right now, I'm trying to pull all of the data from the tables in a single query, and store it as a PHP array I can iterate through. If this is not the best way to go about this process, I can find another way.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just need more experience with MySQL, the trick is in the way you group the elements. In this case you want to group by multiple fields.

```
SELECT 
    products.item as product,
    concat(buyer.f_name,' ',buyer.l_name) as buyer, 
    payment.company as payment,
    count(products.id) as number_purchased
    stores.seller_name as store,
FROM buyer_purchases
    INNER JOIN products
        ON products.id = buyer_purchases.product_listings_id
    INNER JOIN payment
        ON payment.id = buyer_purchases.buyer_id
    INNER JOIN buyer
        ON buyer.id = buyer_purchases.buyer_id
    INNER JOIN stores
        ON stores.id = buyer_purchases.product_listings_stores_id
GROUP BY buyer.id,stores.id,payment.id
ORDER BY products.item
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple `ORDER BY` clauses which work in order, so looks like you want `ORDER BY products.item, buyer.id` which will list all records for item 1 first, ordered by customer, then all records for item 2 ordered by cutomer etc